# PHP Ajax form validation not passing json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been trying to fix my code a couple of days now, with no luck. I am trying to validate my login form using AJAX. The Jquery AJAX keeps logging the console with

> there was a problem checking the fields

This is my Jquery script which is on the same page as the login form (Jquery is included in the header):

```
var data = {};
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
          resetErrors();
          var url = 'login.php';
          $.each($('form input, form select'), function(i, v) {
              if (v.type !== 'submit') {
                  data[v.name] = v.value;
              }
          }); //end each
          $.ajax({
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'POST',
              url: url,
              data: data,
              success: function(resp) {
                  if (resp === true) {
                        //successful validation
                          $('form').submit();
                        return false;
                  } else {
                      $.each(resp, function(i, v) {
                console.log(i + " => " + v); // view in console for error messages
                          var msg = '<label class="error" for="'+i+'">'+v+'</label>';
                          $('input[name="' + i + '"], select[name="' + i + '"]').addClass('inputTxtError').after(msg);
                      });
                      var keys = Object.keys(resp);
                      $('input[name="'+keys[0]+'"]').focus();
                  }
                  return false;
              },
              error: function() {
                  console.log('there was a problem checking the fields');
              }
          });
          return false;
      });
    });
    function resetErrors() {
        $('form input, form select').removeClass('inputTxtError');
        $('label.error').remove();
    }
```

My form:

```
        <label>Username *</label>
        <input name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus><br>
        <label>Password *</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
```

My PHP (removed code that is not relevant):

```
    else{
        $_SESSION['errors']['user'] = "login failed";
        echo "Login failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
    }
$stmt->close();


        if(count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0){
            if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($_SESSION['errors']);
                exit;
             }
        }
```

After some research by myself I believe there is something wrong with my Jquery, but I have not be able to find out.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: In your AJAX call, you should change the error callback to accept the parameters described in the documentation.  That way you can at least know what type of error is occurring.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: error is called, if the request fails. So there is more likely something wrong with the php-script, then with the jQuery. What does the browser-developer-tool say? (F12)

Comment: @mittmemo it returns a 'parsererror' and a 'syntaxerror: unexpected end of input'.

Comment: @Maikell it just returns the there was something wrong-error, no other errors related to my php or my jquery.

Comment: I don't know what kind of developer-console you're using. Personally I'm using firebug, and there when I click on "console" and make an ajax-request like you do, it shows me the exact server response. Either a 200 (if everything was according to plan) or a 30x, if something was wrong. Then I can click the "response"-tab, and see exactly what the server is saying. http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2642/debugging-tips-how-to-debug-ajax-requests-using-mozilla-firefox-and-firebug Note, that you have to turn on PHP-errors, to actually find the error

Comment: @Maikell it responds with a 200 OK

Comment: Also, when I do not include the: "dataType: 'json'," it does not give me an error. But then the part of the jquery script which outputs possible errors does not output anything either.

Answer (score 0):

your code having many complexion try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE 'html'>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<form id="frmAdd" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
 <label>Username *</label>
        <input name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus><br>
        <label>Password *</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
</form>

<script>
var data = {};
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#frmAdd").validate({
         submitHandler: function() {
                    $("#frmAdd").submit();
                }
       });
      $('#frmAdd').on('submit', function() { 
        var url = 'login.php';
          $.each($('form input, form select'), function(i, v) { 
              if (v.type !== 'submit') {
                  data[v.name] = v.value;
                }
          }); //end each
          $.ajax({
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'POST',
              url: url,
              data: data,
              success: function(resp) {
                  if (resp === true) {
                        //successful validation
                          $('form').submit();
                        return false;
                  } else {
                      $.each(resp, function(i, v) {
                console.log(i + " => " + v); // view in console for error messages
                          var msg = '<label class="error" for="'+i+'">'+v+'</label>';
                          $('input[name="' + i + '"], select[name="' + i + '"]').addClass('inputTxtError').after(msg);
                      });
                      var keys = Object.keys(resp);
                      $('input[name="'+keys[0]+'"]').focus();
                  }
                  return false;
              },
              error: function() {
                  console.log('there was a problem checking the fields');
              }
          });
          return false;
      });

    });

</script>
        </body>
</html>
```